Weird squared reflection on metal material
I want to make a good render of this tube and i use an STL file for the model. As you can see the reflections on the metal material look weird and very squared. Currently i use the EdgeSplit and Subdivision modifier to make it better. It helps a bit but i do not get it to look better than the picture below. Does one of you have a suggestion/solution how i can make these renders look more natural?
Link: 


Hello, if Etienne's answer doesn't help, please share your file

Hi moonboots, I do not see where I can enter a blender file

you can use https://blend-exchange.com/ read the instructions

Thank you, i have uploaded the file

Have you tried to shade smooth the mesh ?
(when the mesh is selected in object mode,right click and shade smooth or shade smooth by angle)
Hope this helps,
Etienne

Yes i have applied the shadesmooth/autosmooth, still these reflections are there
